# Compiling CUPS: undefined reference to `dnssdDeregisterAllPrinters'

Tags: ubuntu, compile, make, cups

I'm trying to build CUPS 1.7.3 on Ubuntu Server 14.04. `configure` didn't produce any errors, but `make` dies with:

```
Making all in ppdc...
Making all in scheduler...
Linking cupsd...
dirsvc.o: In function `cupsdStopBrowsing':
/root/cups-source/cups-1.7.3/scheduler/dirsvc.c:262: undefined reference to `dnssdDeregisterAllPrinters'
dirsvc.o: In function `cupsdStartBrowsing':
/root/cups-source/cups-1.7.3/scheduler/dirsvc.c:244: undefined reference to `dnssdRegisterAllPrinters'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cupsd] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I couldn't find anything useful on Google, other than some refrences to `zeroconf` and `avahi`. I tried installing `avahi-daemon` and `avahi-autoipd`, but same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install libavahi-cil-dev libavahi-client-dev libavahi-common-dev
```

seems to solve the problem. Not sure if all are required, but make completed without errors, so hopefully this helps someone else.